# Android: Fatal Exception in System Process: ActivityManager

Tags: android, android-activity, rooted-device

After months of work, some Android tablet devices (rooted) on the company that I work, randomly are getting a "White Screen" after the boot animation. Also, some of them reboot several times before getting established on a white screen.

For those devices that are rebooting, I can see on logcat that it is stopping in the exception below:

```
D/NetlinkEvent(  167): NL subsys is 'block'
D/NetlinkEvent(  167): NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/sprd-sdhci.3/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p21'
D/NetlinkEvent(  167): NL param 'MAJOR=179'
D/NetlinkEvent(  167): NL param 'MINOR=21'
D/NetlinkEvent(  167): NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p21'
D/NetlinkEvent(  167): NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
D/NetlinkEvent(  167): NL param 'PARTN=21'
D/NetlinkEvent(  167): NL param 'PARTNAME=userdata'
I/DirectVolume(  167): ++ok_vold----in_handleBolckEvent() in_if*it:/devices/sprd-sdhci.3/mmc_host/mmc0-----
E/DirectVolume(  167): making device node '/dev/block/vold/179:21'
W/DirectVolume(  167): Ignore partition userdata
D/WCND    (  171): is_cp2_alive_ok: open polling interface: /dev/spipe_wcn0, fd = 12
D/WCND    (  171): is_cp2_alive_ok: loop: /dev/spipe_wcn0 is OK
I/Zygote  (  178): ...preloaded 1463 classes in 2501ms.
D/libEGL  (  178): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
I/Zygote  (  178): ZytoteInit preload finish
D/dalvikvm(  178): GC_EXPLICIT freed 467K, 16% free 2665K/3136K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm(  178): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 16% free 2660K/3136K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm(  178): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 16% free 2660K/3136K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm(  178): System server process 647 has been created
I/Zygote  (  178): Accepting command socket connections
D/SensorService(  647): nuSensorService starting...
I/SystemServer(  647): Entered the Android system server!
D/Sensors (  647): AnumSensors=1; 1
E/IAtChannel(  180): Couldn't get connection to atchannel0
D/audio_hw_primary(  180): do_cmd_dual Switch incall AT command [AT+VGR=6][ERROR]
E/audio_hw_primary(  180): do_voice_command: X
I/audio_hw_primary(  180):  voice_command_thread_entry looping done.
I/audio_hw_primary(  180):  voice_command_thread_entry looping now...
D/SDCARD  (  188): missing packages.list; retrying
D/SDCARD  (  191): missing packages.list; retrying
D/Sensors (  647): PnumSensors=2; 2
D/Sensors (  647): activate handle=0; drv=0
D/Sensors (  647): activate handle=4; drv=1
D/Sensors (  647): PlsSensor::enable en=0; newState=0; what=0; mEnabled=0
I/SensorService(  647): STK8312 3-axis Accelerometer
I/SensorService(  647): AL3006 Proximity sensor
D/SensorService(  647): Max socket buffer size 163840
D/SensorService(  647): nuSensorService thread starting...
I/installd(  181): new connection
I/SystemServer(  647): Waiting for installd to be ready.
I/Installer(  647): connecting...
I/SystemServer(  647): Power Manager
D/PowerManagerService(  647): Acquiring suspend blocker "PowerManagerService.Display".
I/SystemServer(  647): Activity Manager
W/dalvikvm(  647): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415e5bc0)
I/Process (  647): Sending signal. PID: 647 SIG: 9
E/installd(  181): eof
E/installd(  181): failed to read size
I/installd(  181): closing connection
I/Zygote  (  178): Exit zygote because system server (647) has terminated
E/AndroidRuntime(  647): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: ActivityManager
E/AndroidRuntime(  647): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x10e0009
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1139)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at android.content.res.SPRDResources.getValue(SPRDResources.java:182)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.updateOomLevels(ProcessList.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.<init>(ProcessList.java:179)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.<init>(ActivityManagerService.java:485)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerServiceEx.<init>(ActivityManagerServiceEx.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1955)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647): Error reporting crash
E/AndroidRuntime(  647): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime(  647):        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
I/ServiceManager(  166): service 'power' died
I/ServiceManager(  166): service 'sensorservice' died
D/SDCARD  (  188): missing packages.list; retrying
D/SDCARD  (  191): missing packages.list; retrying
D/WCND    (  171): is_cp2_alive_ok: open polling interface: /dev/spipe_wcn0, fd = 12
D/WCND    (  171): is_cp2_alive_ok: loop: /dev/spipe_wcn0 is OK
D/SDCARD  (  188): missing packages.list; retrying
D/SDCARD  (  191): missing packages.list; retrying
D/SDCARD  (  188): missing packages.list; retrying
D/SDCARD  (  191): missing packages.list; retrying
D/WCND    (  171): is_cp2_alive_ok: open polling interface: /dev/spipe_wcn0, fd = 12
D/WCND    (  171): is_cp2_alive_ok: loop: /dev/spipe_wcn0 is OK
D/SDCARD  (  188): missing packages.list; retrying
D/SDCARD  (  191): missing packages.list; retrying
D/WCND    (  171): is_cp2_alive_ok: open polling interface: /dev/spipe_wcn0, fd = 12
D/WCND    (  171): is_cp2_alive_ok: loop: /dev/spipe_wcn0 is OK
D/SDCARD  (  188): missing packages.list; retrying
D/SDCARD  (  191): missing packages.list; retrying
PS C:\adb>
```

For those who are working on "white screen", I can see that the principal GUI is running on the back of white scree. I can confirm this by taking a screenshot and open it on my computer. Also, the touch screen is working and I can select some functions through the buttons of the GUI. This is also checked when I take another screenshot.

Why ActivityManager is showing fatal exceptions sometimes?
Why, when the system starts, I can only see a blank screen without any colored pixels?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For those interesting, this issue was solved when I reloaded the Android ROM on the device. We suspect that, because the device was working for more than 3 years directly and saving tons of logs inside internal MMC memory, we achieved the memory cycle write limit, and the system was corrupted. So, after reloading the ROM, the device starts to work properly again. Maybe we will substitute this MMC to offer some more "life" for those devices.